# Extract the column from the inner data frame within a list of lists of lists

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, sapply

I am trying to extract a column from a dataframe that is stored as an element inside a list of lists, there are a total of 100 models where 10 different data models are stored in an individual list. This individual list then contains the dataframe. (The depth of the top nested list is up three)

Furthermore, I want to save these column values and place them in a separate dataframe which I'm trying with rbind.

I am able to get all the values from the final dataframe but not specifically the column of interest and am not sure which values belong to which model, this is done as seen below:

### with apply

Here I am able to obtain all the values but am not able to use dplyr to conduct further selection

```
importance <- sapply(unlist(myNestedList, recursive = FALSE), `[[`, 9)
```

### with base r and dplyr

```
meanDF <- data.frame() 

#Loop through ModelsList
for (i in seq_along(top_list)) {
  for (j in seq_along(top_list[[i]])) {
    for (x in seq_along(top_list[[i]][[j]])) {
      test <- as.data.frame(top_list[[i]][[j]]$importance) %>%
        select(Mean) %>%
        arrange(desc(Mean)) %>%
        slice(1:50) %>%
        rownames_to_column(var = "Bus") %>%
        mutate(RF = j) %>%
        rename(value = Mean)
      
      #Append to Dataframe
  meanDF <- rbind(meanDF, test)
    }
  }
}
```

### dataset example

```
n1 <- 100 ; m <- 200 ; reps <- 6
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(m), n1, m/n1), 
                           replicate(reps, sample(c(0, 1), n1, replace = TRUE))))

n2 <- 100 ; m <- 200 ; reps <- 4
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(m), n2, m/n2), 
                           replicate(reps, sample(c(0, 1), n2, replace = TRUE))))


# create a list and create 3 lists 
# inside this list
top_list = list(list1 = list(list2 = list(df1)),
                list3 = list(list4 = list(df2)))
```

Comment: You need to share a reproducible example of your dataset.

Comment: @M-- correct, I just put an example of what I'm working with :)

Comment: Use the same naming convention in your example, i.e. `myNestedList`. I assume `top_list` is the example of what `myNestedList` would look like. right?

Comment: @M-- yes correct, I have changed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use

```
library(purrr)
map_depth(top_list, 3, pluck, 2)
```

---

Or use recursive function

```
library(rrapply)
rrapply(top_list, classes = "data.frame", f= \(x) x[[2]], how = "flatten")
```

-output

```
$`1`
  [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
 [44] 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186
 [87] 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200

$`1`
  [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
 [44] 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186
 [87] 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
```

Comment: This takes only one element of the list, I have multiple dataframes in my list of lists that I need to extract.

Comment: @informaticianwannabe your title was `Extracting data column from a dataframe`.  here the code extracts the 2nd column from the inner data.frame

Comment: @informaticianwannabe maybe the data you created as reproducible is not a replica of your actual data

Comment: sorry for the lack of reproducibility, this is how my code looks like but yes, you are right, I should have made it more reproducible/replicate..

Comment: I've also changed the title of the question...

Comment: @informaticianwannabe the rrapply code should work even if different list elements have different depths.  You could change the column number to extract

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, I found it easier to unlist the original list of lists with a depth of three and search recursively through this:

```
top_list <- unlist(top_list, recursive = F)

  ##Create an empty dataframe
  empty_df <- data.frame()    
  
  #Recursively extract column values from ModelList
  for (i in seq_along(ml_models)) {
    
    columnValues <- as.data.frame(ml_models[[i]][[df_of_interest]]) %>%
      select(column) %>% 
      arrange(desc(column)) %>%
      slice(1:no_features) %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "Column") %>%
      mutate(model = i) %>%
      rename(value = column)
    
    #Append to Dataframe
    empty_df <- rbind(empty_df, columnValues)
```